# Find gradient of curve $y=2x^3 - 5x^2 -x+1$ at point $(2,-5)$. Continue in description!

Tags: calculus

Find the $x$-coordinate of another point on the curve where the tangent at that point is parallel to the tangent at point $(2,-5)$

EDIT: well here it goes..from $y= 2x^3 - 5x^2 -x+1$ ....after doing calculus I got the gradient which is $m = 3$ ...the word "here the tangent at that point is parallel to the tangent at point $(2,-5)$" confuses me however..therefore I need help!!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! People here are willing to help but, please, show your efforts. Explain what you already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi sorry, I'm super new here, well here it goes..from y= 2x^3 - 5x^2 -x+1 ....after doing calculus I got the gradient which is m = 3 ...the word "here the tangent at that point is parallel to the tangent at point (2,-5)" confuses me however..therefore I need help!! >.< @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

To find another point where the gradient is $3$, we have to solve:

$y'=3 \Leftrightarrow 6x^2-10x-1=3$

---

.. the tangent at that point is parallel to the tangent at point .. means: .. the tangents have the same slope.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir! But...does this mean..3=6x^2 - 10x-1 ? Then you get 0=6x^2-10x-4....Using calculator, I get x = 2 and -1/3 ..which is the answer? I think it would be -1/3 because the other x point is already 2...so am I right? -1/3 ??

Comment: Yes, the tangents in both $x=-\frac13$ and $x=2$ have slope $3$, and since you're looking for a point other than $x=2$, the answer is $x=-\frac13$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Anyway sir, I'd like to ask another question, am I allowed to ask more than 1 question everyday? Or is there any limit to ask questions? I'm sorry if I did skip this part in the rules earlier >.<!

Comment: You are allowed to ask multiple questions, but it's preferable that you open another post. I will help you there.